# Conversion data type issue when UPDATE a NULL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, nullable, sqldatatypes

I've got a query as below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp1
end

SELECT * into #Temp1
   from (
          SELECT 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 9, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
)
as databases (tempid, tasknr, devcat, taskop, taskcl)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1a') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp1a
end

SELECT * into #Temp1a
   from (
select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_change ORDER BY number)as int) as tempid
,number as tasknr
,category as cat
,orig_date_entered as taskop
,case when (CM3TM1.status = 'closed') then CM3TM1.date_entered else NULL end as taskcl
FROM CM3TM1
WHERE parent_change IN ('C45168')
and category = 'NEU Development' 
)
as databases (tempid, tasknr, devcat, taskop, taskcl)


UPDATE
    #Temp1
SET
    #Temp1.tasknr = #Temp1a.tasknr,
    #Temp1.devcat = #Temp1a.devcat
FROM
    #Temp1a
INNER JOIN
    #Temp1
ON
    #Temp1.tempid = #Temp1a.tempid
```

and I'm getting

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 38 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'T85158' to data type int.

T85158 is related to 'tasknr' column.

I need to update such NULL table with different types of data where number of rows is changeable. I had tried to add `,cast((number) as int) as tasknr`
but it didn't help.
Please let me know how to make this work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the error is correctly put by Damien. Below is just another flavor of the possible fix. 
Modify your upper part of script to this:

```
SELECT * into #Temp1
   from (
          SELECT 1 tempid, cast (NULL as varchar(19)) tasknr , cast(NULL as decimal(13,4)) devcat, cast(NULL as int) taskop, cast(NULL as xml) taskcl
UNION ALL SELECT 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 9, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
)

.......
```

**Edit:** To `DELETE` those rows which have every column as NULL, use this script:

```
DELETE FROM #temp1 WHERE
COALESCE(tasknr,devcat,taskop,taskcl) IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks again, it works as well. If I could have one more question: how to eliminate rows where only first column (tempid) is  not NULL?

Comment: You mean you want to eliminates those rows where tempid is `NOT NULL` **and** other columns ARE `NULL`?

Comment: The point is I've got 15 tables as the mentioned one, and every of them got now 10 rows and after UPDATE some of the rows are not NULL. I joined them and now I'd like to remove rows which are only with NULLs in every column from joined tables.

Comment: Is it possible to use it after FULL JOIN because when I use it before that, I won't be able to make FULL JOIN correctly because there is a different number of rows for each of tables. I would like to remove NULL columns from the final results.

Comment: Sure you can do it. Have the final dataset in a new temp table and apply the DELETE on that.

Comment: You're amazing, thanks again! It works, Now I've got "Expression type int is invalid for COLLATE clause." issue but I will try to find a way to fix this, I've already got more help as I expected. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You're giving SQL Server no type information to use when you create `#temp1` so it's (apparently) decided that every column is of type `int`. If you want to have columns of particular types, prefer to create the table explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (
    tempid int not null,
    tasknr varchar(19) null,
    devcat decimal(13,4) null,
    taskop int null,
    taskcl xml null
)
INSERT INTO #temp1(tempid, tasknr, devcat, taskop, taskcl) VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(9, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

...
```